# Can't swipe-delete a notification from service

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I have a service which downloads data, runs in a separate process (so that it doesn't die/restart when the app is closed) and shows a notification with it's progress. I want to be able to stop the service if the user swipe-deletes the notification, but have so far been unable to do it. Relevant code below:

DatabaseDownloadService.java

```
public class DatabaseDownloadService extends Service
{
    private final static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1337;
    private final static String NOTIFICATION_DISMISSAL_TAG = "my_notification_dismissal_tag";
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = getNotification("Downloading database...");
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

        startDownloadingStuff();
    }

    private Notification getNotification(String text)
    {
        NotificationDismissedReceiver receiver = new NotificationDismissedReceiver();
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(NOTIFICATION_DISMISSAL_TAG));

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationDismissedReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent deleteIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, NOTIFICATION_ID, intent, 0);

        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("My Awesome App")
                .setContentText(text)
                .setDeleteIntent(deleteIntent)
                .build();
    }

    public class NotificationDismissedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            int notificationId = intent.getExtras().getInt(NOTIFICATION_DISMISSAL_TAG);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Download cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Do more logic stuff here once this works...
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    ... properties and activities go here...>

    <service
        android:name=".DatabaseDownloadService"
        android:process=":dds_process"
        android:enabled="true"/>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.myapp.DatabaseDownloadService$NotificationDismissedReceiver"
        android:exported="false"/>

</application>
```

As far as I can tell, the .setDeleteIntent() should make the notification swipe-deletable, which should then send a broadcast, which should then be caught by my NotificationDismissedReceiver. However, as it stands, I can't even swipe-delete the notification, and I never see the "Download cancelled" Toast...

Comment: I think you are running into a limitation of the platform when using `startForeground`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26576872/how-do-i-remove-a-foreground-notification-in-android-lollipop

Comment: As per official documentation:
`Make this service run in the foreground, supplying the ongoing notification to be shown to the user while in this state.`
But you can create a pending intent that closes the service as soon as its clicked firing the pending Intent that actually stops the service - thus removing the notification

Answer (score 3):

You can call to stop the service from foreground, passing false, means not remove the notification. For Android N and above, you can pass STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH also.

```
stopForeground(false);
```

After that you can stop the service by yourself also.

```
stopSelf();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using startForeground(), use :

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify("tag", NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: The reason I'm using startForeground() is that I want the service to carry on doing its thing even if the user closes the app. Using notify() will make the service restart when the app is closed, which is not the behaviour I want.

Comment: Did you try explicitly setting setOngoing(false) while building your notification ?