# Can we avoid stopForeground to stop Service

Tags: android, android-service, foregroundnotification

I have a Service which I use ExoPlayer to play music in it. I am displaying a notification for my app as it is a Foreground Service and I keep updating Notification in onPlayerStateChanged callback method of ExoPlayer :

```
@Override
public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
    ...
    showNotification(state, sample);
}

private void showNotification(PlaybackStateCompat state, Sample sample) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "Id");

    int icon;
    String play_pause;
    if (state.getState() == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING) {
        icon = R.drawable.exo_controls_pause;
        play_pause = getString(R.string.pause);
    } else {
        icon = R.drawable.exo_controls_play;
        play_pause = getString(R.string.play);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Action playPauseAction = new NotificationCompat.Action(
            icon, play_pause,
            MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this,
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE));

    NotificationCompat.Action restartAction = new NotificationCompat
            .Action(R.drawable.exo_controls_previous, getString(R.string.restart),
            MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent
                    (this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS));

    NotificationCompat.Action nextAction = new NotificationCompat
            .Action(R.drawable.exo_controls_next, getString(R.string.next),
            MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent
                    (this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT));

    PendingIntent contentPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity
            (this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, StopServiceBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

    builder.setContentTitle(sample.getTitle())
            .setContentText(sample.getComposer())
            .setContentIntent(contentPendingIntent)
            .setDeleteIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_music_note)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .addAction(restartAction)
            .addAction(playPauseAction)
            .addAction(nextAction).setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
            .setMediaSession(mMediaSession.getSessionToken())
            .setShowActionsInCompactView(1, 2));

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        String channelId = "Id";
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                channelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        builder.setChannelId(channelId);
    }

    Notification notificationCompat = builder.build();
    if (state.getState() == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED) {
        stopForeground(false);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationCompat);
    } else {
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationCompat);
    }
}
```

As you see at the end of the method when state is `PAUSE`, I `stopForeground`. This will destroy Service within a minute, and as a result notification will be dismissed as discussed in following thread : https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5954

I am a user of SoundCloud app. In their app, it seems that when state is `PAUSE`, they have also `stopForeground` since notification is dismissible. But if I do not dismiss notification manually, notification stays in status bar for always, and it seems Service is not destroyed in their app. `The scenario that I explained for SoundCloud is just a guess`

Do you think how it has been implemented in their app?

If something need to be checked, full source code of my sample can be found here : https://github.com/AliRezaeiii/ExoPlayerSample

```
/**
     * Release ExoPlayer.
     */
    private void releasePlayer() {
        mExoPlayer.removeListener(this);
        mExoPlayer.stop();
        mExoPlayer.release();
        mExoPlayer = null;
    }

    /**
     * Release the player when the service is destroyed.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy()");
        super.onDestroy();
        releasePlayer();
        mMediaSession.setActive(false);
    }
```

Comment: "and it seems Service is not destroyed in their app" -- that seems unlikely. "Do you think how it has been implemented in their app?" -- I think that their service is destroyed. There should be an `adb shell` command that you can run to determine whether or not they have a running service. "and as a result notification will be dismissed as discussed" -- try using a different ID for the `notify()` call. Or, try calling `notify()` before `startForeground()`.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. In my app when Service destroyed, notification also will be dismissed, but in SoundCloud notification stays in status bar for always. How they have implemented this solution?

Comment: "How they have implemented this solution?" -- presumably, they have their own notification that is decoupled from the one used with `startForeground()`. Normally, a notification is not tied to having a running service. However, it may be that there is something about a notification that had been used solely for `startForeground()` that is causing your symptoms. That is why I made the specific suggestions in my previous comment, to try to get you a notification that is not harmed by having used it for `startForeground()`.

Comment: I thought about your solution. I can use a decoupled notification from the one used with `startForeground`, but when service destroyed, I release instance of ExoPlayer ( You can see that at the end of my question), So the notification action buttons can not execute play, next or prev song since instance of ExoPlayer is released. I really appreciate if you give me any suggestion on that.

Comment: Your notification buttons would trigger a new instance of the foreground service, which can set up ExoPlayer for playback. You need to save the context of where you were when you paused playback (e.g., what song you were on, what offset from the song start you were at), and you would use that information to pick things up where the user left off.

Comment: My assumption for notification when State is PAUSED :
`stopForeground(true);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationCompat);`

For some milli second notification dismissed and then new notification appears which is not harmed by having used it for `startForeground()`. But I guess my assumption is not that correct since in SoundCloud notification does not dismiss even for a milli second. What could be the best practice?

Comment: As I suggested earlier, try calling `notify()` before `startForeground()`. Maybe using the same ID is fine, if the notification is raised on its own separately, before you use it for the foreground service. In the end, this simply is not a scenario that I have had to deal with, so I am just guessing.

Comment: I found the solution for that here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49100515/keeping-notification-from-dismissing-when-service-is-destroyed-in-oreo